# RegEx return multiple matches between anchor points

Tags: regex

I need to perform a match that will return multiple occurrences BUT this needs to be limited by an anchor point in the target string.

My RegEx pattern would be e would be `tag(.*)/tag`

against a string of: *(line breaks just to make it easier to read)*

```
tagcatch 1/tag
tagcatch 2/tag
tagcatch 3/tag
Only catch above this
tagcatch 4/tag
tagcatch 5/tag
tagcatch 6/tag
```

Which happily returns multiple named groups containing catch 1 through catch 6.  This works well but what I need is for the scope to be limited to the start of the string and the phrase

*Only catch above this*

So my groups would only contain catch 1 through catch 3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am stumped at what seems to be a simple enough task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Positive Lookahead to assert that the phrase follows.

```
(?s)tag(.*?)/tag(?=.*\bOnly catch above this)
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/yV9iO7/1)

Answer (score 0):

in case you have `Only catch above this` repeated multiple times, use this pattern

```
Only catch above this.*$|tag(.*?)/tag
```

with `s` option
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yV9iO7/2)